# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'message' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `messages`

Tags: laravel

[the message controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AL0Ni.png)

please help me find the error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'message' in
> 'field list' (SQL: insert into `messages`

Comment: The error says you do not have `message` column in the `messages` table.

Comment: Can you post the database migration that creates the `messages` table?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to insert a value to `messages` column in the database but SQL is complaining that it doesn't exist.

Open phpmyadmin and check if you do indeed have column named `messages` in the table, if not create one.